# Magento 2 url rewrite cann't work with querystring

Tags: magento2, attributes, url-rewrite

I want to rewrite url from "men.html?brand=147" to "men/nike.html"

I tried to add new custom rewrite url in Admin but it wasn't take querystring "?brand=147"

How can i fix that! Thank you!!!

Comment: SEO Url is on in backend?

Answer (score 0):

Magento neglect query string during URL rewrites. You can use web server URL rewrites.

In  Apache:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^brand=147$
RewriteRule ^/men.html men/nike.html
```